# Datepicker MinDate maxDate, maxDate = datestart + 3 months

Tags: datepicker, date-range, daterangepicker

Using the basic two input field datepicker format.
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

### Input1:

```
$(function() {
    $("#DATE_START").datepicker({ showOtherMonths: true, minDate: +1, dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd", });
});
```

### Input2:

```
$(function() {
    $("#DATE_END").datepicker({ showOtherMonths: true, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, minDate: +2, dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd", });
});
```

### Issue:

I want the DATE_END to be DATE_START input value, plus 3 months.
EX: maxDate = DATE_START + '3m'
Not needed current date plus 3 months

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have just to set the Date like this:

```
$(function() { $("#DATE_START").datepicker({ showOtherMonths: true, minDate: "+3m", dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd", }); })
$( "#DATE_END" ).datepicker.datepicker({ showOtherMonths: true, minDate: "+3m", dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd", }); })
```

Have a look on the documentation. Its pretty good.
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

You can also use this to set the date:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
```

Comment: Hi, your reply is appreciated, but it does not solve the issue of DATE_END 3m after DATE_START, your solution provides a static setDate value, where I'm looking for a dynamic value which starts at DATE_START.